# TypeScript infer function return type from parameter enum values

Tags: typescript, enums, type-inference, return-type

I'm using this function to tranform enum to an object which has enum values for properties and empty option lists for their values:

```
export const createDictOfEmptyOptionListsFromEnum = ( 
  enum: Record<string | number, string | number>
) => {
  type OutputEntry = [number | string, Option[]];

  const enumValues = Object.values(enum);
  const entries = enumValues.map((val): OutputEntry => [val, []]);
  return Object.fromEntries(entries);
};
```

which results in return type of  `{ [k: string] : Option[] }`

I then need to manually narrow the return type like this:

```
type MyEnumOptionDict = { [k in MyEnum]: Option[] };
const dict: MyEnumOptionDict = createEmptyOptionDict(MyEnum);
```

Is there a way to

1. Make Typescript infer the narrowed return type automaticaly or
2. at least make a generic type that would return the narrowed input type when provided the enum

Comment: For starters, `createDictOfEmptyOptionListsFromEnum = <E extends Record<string | number, string | number>(enum: E)`. Then remove the `OutputEntry` type. It is confusing and your usage inhibits type inference.

Comment: What is `MyEnum` and how are you meant to transform `string | number` into `MyEnum`s?

Comment: Actually, I realized my suggestion won't work because you're using the enum values as keys of the resulting object. That could result in some very hard to track down bugs because you could easily end up duplicate keys in the resulting object.

Comment: @AluanHaddad The `OutputEntry` type is there, because otherwise TS infers the entry to be `[string | number | any[]][]`.

Comment: `MyEnum` is any TS [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

Comment: @AluanHaddad Good point about duplicate keys... I thought enum values must be unique, but they don't. My enums are, however. And since I'm assigning a constant to to all of the keys, the duplicates wouldn't really matter.

Comment: Anyway, you can make it work but only with a type assertion or create an additional overload signature for `fromEntries`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I managed to succesfuly assert the type upon function return, based on your recommendation in the first comment (`return Object.fromEntries(entries) as { [k in E[keyof E]]: Option[]; }`). I will accept that as an answer, if you care to make one. Thank you!